# Incorrect user delete from list on sever side

Tags: java, sockets, server

I have a small primitive server for studying, and client side.
Here I have piece of my server code:

```
 public class Connector implements Runnable, SocketListener {

    private Socket socket;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private List<ServerSideClient> clients = new LinkedList<>();
    private boolean triger;

    public Connector(ServerSocket serverSocket) {
        this.serverSocket = serverSocket;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Waiting for clients..");
                triger = true;
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Client connected");
                ServerSideClient client = createClient();
                client.setConnection(true);
                client.startListeningClient();

                clients.add(client);

                new Thread(() -> {
                    socketIsClosed(client);
                }).start();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private ServerSideClient createClient() {
        return new ServerSideClient(socket);
    }


    @Override
    public synchronized void socketIsClosed(ServerSideClient client) {
        while (triger == true) {
            if (client.isConnected() == false) {
                triger = false;
                clients.remove(client);
                System.out.println("Client was removed " + clients.size());
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Here we wait for new Client, then create client instance and add it to LinkedList. In instance on server side we waiting information from client and sending answer on separated thread. But when client closes connection with server, `socketIsClosed()` method should to delete current client reference from collection. But when client is disconnected I haven't even Logout `System.out.println("Client was removed " + clients.size());` from `socketIsClosed(ServerSideClient client)` method.

Client Code:

```
public class Client {

    private final String HOST = "localhost";
    private final int PORT = 1022;
    private InputStream inputStream;
    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    private Socket socket;

    private boolean connection;

    public Client() throws IOException {
        socket = new Socket();
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(HOST, PORT));
        inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
        outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client client = null;
        try {
            client = new Client();
            client.work();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void work() {
        connection = true;
        listenForConsoleInput();
        receiveAnswerFromServer();
    }

    private void listenForConsoleInput() {
        new Thread(() -> {

            while (connection == true) {
                String requset = null;
                try {

                    requset = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    if (requset.equals(".")) {
                        closeConnection();
                        return;
                    } else {
                        sendRequest(requset);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }).start();
    }

    private void sendRequest(String request) {
        try {
            outputStream.write(request.getBytes());
            outputStream.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void receiveAnswerFromServer() {
        new Thread(() -> {
            while (connection == true) {
                byte[] data = new byte[32 * 1024];
                try {
                    int numberOfBytes = inputStream.read(data);
                    System.out.println("Server>> " + new String(data, 0, numberOfBytes));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    closeConnection();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void closeConnection() {
        try {
            connection = false;
            socket.close();
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

`socketIsClosed(ServerSideClient client)` method works in separated thread.

```
public class ServerSideClient {

    private Socket socket;
    private InputStream in;
    private OutputStream out;

    private boolean connection;
    private int numOfBytes;

    public boolean isConnected() {
        return connection;
    }

    public void setConnection(boolean connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    public ServerSideClient(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
        try {
            in = socket.getInputStream();
            out = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void startListeningClient() {
        new Thread(() -> {
            listenUsers();
        }).start();
    }

    private void listenUsers() {
        while (connection == true) {
            byte[] data = new byte[32 * 1024];

            readInputFromClient(data);
            if (numOfBytes == -1) {
                try {
                    connection = false;
                    socket.close();
                    in.close();
                    out.close();
                    isConnected();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Client disconected..");
                return;
            }
            String requestFromClient = new String(data, 0, numOfBytes);
            System.out.println("Client sended>> " + requestFromClient);


            sendResponce(requestFromClient);

        }

    }

    private void readInputFromClient(byte[] data) {
        try {
            numOfBytes = in.read(data);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void sendResponce(String resp) {
        try {
            out.write(resp.getBytes());
            out.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I trying to resolve this problem since 2 week, Helllllllp.....

Comment: Hi @Andriy, I added an answer working with your case.

Comment: Thanks Bro!! Could you summary, what was my main mistake? I'm not so experience dev... Or, why we should create a new class? Is that just pretty good or necessary? And can the problem be resolved by java rx using?

Comment: Hi @Andriy, sure. The Main was: the variable trigger was shared, and setting to true every iteration in the loop, what you were checking in another thread and setting to false after, this would set false for all the connections (same value for all threads as it was shared). Second, yes. It is a good approach to have a separated class for one unique purpose like listening to closed connections.

Comment: Another way was to use Observable pattern or Rx Java like you said, where you subscribe to what you want to listen. And instead of sockets, you could use Publish/Subscribe pattern, like here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-java.html

Comment: Thanks, I understood what are you talking about.. I have a one, last ask for you: Could you advice a source about javarx... All what I found is hard for understanding for me.. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, I particularly like https://www.baeldung.com/rx-java and https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/RxJava/article.html#using-reactive-programming-with-rxjava-2-0. They websites always help me.

Comment: Thank you Brother, you helped me very much. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I decided this problem with javaRX library. I just used event that send to observer server state. In Observable class I've created:

```
private PublishSubject<Boolean> subject = PublishSubject.create();
    public Observable<Boolean> observable = subject.asObservable();


    public void setConnection(boolean connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
        subject.onNext(this.connection);
    }
```

Method `setConnection()` set true if client has been connected and false if client initialized disconnect.

In Observer class I initialized an instance of Observable class, and initialized subscription:

```
client = createClient();
client.observable.subscribe(state -> removeClient(state));



public void removeClient(Boolean state) {
        System.out.println("Server state " + state);
        if (state == false) {
            clients.remove(client);
            System.out.println("Client remowed. List size: " + clients.size());
        }
    }
```

Now, I always know about server state, and make client removing if last has initialized disconnection.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate your problem, and as a easy solution to fix is creating a class SocketClosedListener:

```
class SocketClosedListener implements Runnable {

     private final ServerSideClient client;
     private List<ServerSideClient> clients;

     public SocketClosedListener(ServerSideClient client, List<ServerSideClient> clients) {
        this.client = client;
         this.clients = clients;
     }

     @Override
     public void run() {
         while (true) {
             if (!client.isConnected()) {
                 clients.remove(client);
                 System.out.println("Client was removed " + clients.size());
                 return;
             }
             try {
                 Thread.sleep(100);
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

And inside your run() method in the Connector class, we have this call:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Waiting for clients..");
            triger = true;
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Client connected");
            ServerSideClient client = createClient();
            client.setConnection(true);
            client.startListeningClient();

            clients.add(client);

            new Thread(new SocketClosedListener(client, clients)).start();//added

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The line added:

```
new Thread(new SocketClosedListener(client, clients)).start();
```

It is responsible to be looking for client when disconnected in a separated thread. Also a delay of 100ms to avoid checking each ms that can cause issues when multiple threads running.

With this code I was able to have this in the console:

```
Waiting for clients..
Client sended>> hi
Client disconected..
Client was removed 1
Client disconected..
Client was removed 0
```

Comment: Notice: I don't use the method signature socketIsClosed(ServerSideClient client), because you have the client when creating the class.